# How can I navigate between applications in kali linux with shortcut keys?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I navigate between applications just by using keyboad? I want to go right and left between applications but the arrow keys not working for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From within Overview mode; use `ctrl`+`alt`+`tab` to change keyboard focus. select the 'app icon' - this will allow you to navigate through the app icons with the `arrow` keys.

For more general keyboard navigation in Gnome-Shell, for switching between apps;

`alt+tab` will allow switching between running apps. follow that by using the `arrow` keys will allow you to navigate left and right between open applications.

but if you mean in Gnome's application Overview (your screenshot), it is fastest to just hit the `Super` key and then type of the app name; by the 2nd or 3rd letter you just just hit `enter` to launch the app.

Alternatively, you could setup an app on each workspace, then to navigate between them; `ctrl`+`alt`+`left/right` arrow keys. -- this is a fairly normal workflow in Gnome.

ref: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-nav.html.en

Comment: .No I do not need to switch between open applications or workspaces. I just want to go right and left in the picture that I send.

Comment: `ctrl`+`alt`+`tab` will allow you to change keyboard focus when in overview mode, select the app icon option - you should then be able to navigate via arrow keys -- I'll add this to my answer, since you've now clarified what you are trying to do.

Comment: @mohammad_mogmmadi_archangel - reminder: you should accept this as the answer (since it is).